# Mutate multiple comma delimited variable

Tags: r, dataframe

Within my dataframe I have a column with allergens per product. The values within the column 'allergens' are a wide range (milk, peanuts, soja, eggs etc.) and also mentioned in different languages.

Example df:

```
ID    Product         Allergens
1     cow milk        Milk, Milch, Lait
2     Almond milk     Milk, Milk, Almond, Nuts
3     Soja milk       Soja, soja, lait, Lait, Milch
4     Fried Cheese    WHEAT, MILK, MILK, MILK, WHEAT, WHEAT, MILK, CHEESE, MILK, CHEESE, CHEESE, MILK, CHEESE, CHEESE, MILK, CHEESE, WHEAT, BUTTER, CREAM
```

As in the above `df` the allergens are not always all lowercase or uppercase, for example: `Lait` and `lait`.

What would be the most efficient way (the dataset contains almost 250k observations) to mutate all this data and remove duplicates (including the foreign words).

```
ID    Product         Allergens
3     Soja milk       Soja, Milk
4     Fried Cheese    Wheat, Milk, Cheese, Butter, Cream
```

Comment: So do you have a list of these foreign words?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex basically it is any ingredient but in like 7 different languages. So if it is a French dish, the ingredients are in French but if it is a Spanish dish the ingredients will be mentioned in Spanish. The list is way to big to give you the whole list ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Product, ~Allergens,
  1, "cow milk", "Milk, Milch, Lait",
  2, "Almond milk", "Milk, Milk, Almond, Nuts",
  3, "Soja milk", "Soja, soja, lait, Lait, Milch",
  4, "Fried Cheese", "WHEAT, MILK, MILK, MILK, WHEAT, WHEAT, MILK, CHEESE, MILK, CHEESE, CHEESE, MILK, CHEESE, CHEESE, MILK, CHEESE, WHEAT, BUTTER, CREAM"
)
data
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      ID Product     Allergens                                                   
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>                                                       
#> 1     1 cow milk    Milk, Milch, Lait                                           
#> 2     2 Almond milk Milk, Milk, Almond, Nuts                                    
#> 3     3 Soja milk   Soja, soja, lait, Lait, Milch                               
#> 4     4 Fried Chee… WHEAT, MILK, MILK, MILK, WHEAT, WHEAT, MILK, CHEESE, MILK, …

unify <- function(x) {
  x %>% recode(
    "milch" = "milk",
    "lait" = "milk"
  )
}

data %>%
  mutate(Allergens = Allergens %>% str_split(",")) %>%
  unnest(Allergens) %>%
  mutate(
    Allergens = Allergens %>% map_chr(~ .x %>%
      str_trim() %>%
      tolower() %>%
      unique() %>%
      unify())
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID, Product) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    data = data %>% map_chr(~ .x %>%
      pull(Allergens) %>%
      unique() %>%
      paste(collapse = ", "))
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID, Product [4]
#>      ID Product      data                              
#>   <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                             
#> 1     1 cow milk     milk                              
#> 2     2 Almond milk  milk, almond, nuts                
#> 3     3 Soja milk    soja, milk                        
#> 4     4 Fried Cheese wheat, milk, cheese, butter, cream
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>